# What all can be found from the given information?

Tags: statistics

Sums and products of every pair of $n$ numbers are given, however it is not known as which pair's sum and product they are. From this information we can find:

- Mean of the $n$ numbers
- Variance of the $n$ numbers
- Median of $n$ numbers
- Range of the numbers

I know that mean and variance can be found since we would be able to find the sum of the numbers and the sum of their squares.

What about **Median** and **range**?

Comment: Are they integers or reals?

Comment: Nothing else is given. So we can assume reals

Comment: Can we also assume that we know $n$?  One way is to say that the input is presented as a list or multiset with possible duplicate entries, then we can compute $n$ from the length of that list, in which case we also know many pairs correspond to each sum/product. Also, do we know which input numbers are sums and which are products?

Comment: We can assume that we know n. Also what we are given is a list of sums and product of  $\binom{n}{2}$ pairs of numbers in no particular order. The list with the products can be in a different order than the sums (but we don't know that order)

Comment: If they were positive numbers you could take the smallest sum and the smallest product and calculate the smallest number. From there you can go far. But you don't say they are positive so it probably does not help.

Comment: numbers can be positive or negative